# Swift matrix sum

Tags: swift, matrix, sum

I'm trying to develop a func which allows to sum two matrix if they are equals to the same dimension, but I get an error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" on the try.

Here is my Playground:

```
import Foundation

enum RisedError: ErrorType {
    case DimensionNotEquals
    case Obvious(String)
}

func ==(lhs: Matrix, rhs: Matrix) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.rows) == (rhs.rows) && (lhs.columns) == (rhs.columns)
}

protocol Operation {
    mutating func sumWith(matrixB: Matrix) throws -> Matrix
}

struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var grid: [Double]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    }
    func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValidForRow(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var matrixA = Matrix(rows: 2, columns: 2)
matrixA[0,0] = 1.0
matrixA[0,1] = 2.0
matrixA[1,0] = 3.0
matrixA[1,1] = 4.0
var matrixB = Matrix(rows: 2, columns: 2)
matrixB[0,0] = 5.0
matrixB[0,1] = 6.0
matrixB[1,0] = 7.0
matrixB[1,1] = 8.0

print(matrixA)
print(matrixB)

extension Matrix: Operation {

    mutating func sumWith(matrixB: Matrix) throws -> Matrix {

        guard self == matrixB else { throw RisedError.DimensionNotEquals }

        for row in 0...self.rows {
            for column in 0...self.columns {
                self[row, column] = matrixB[row, column] + self[row, column]
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}

do {
    try matrixA.sumWith(matrixB)
} catch RisedError.DimensionNotEquals {
    print("The two matrix's dimensions aren't equals")
} catch {
    print("Something very bad happens")
}
```

Here is the error Log:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the rest of the error log?

Comment: Do you really define `A == B` to be true if just the matrix *dimensions* are the same?

Comment: If something unexpected happens in the Playground: 1) Use a compiled project instead, and 2) use the *debugger* to single-step through your code. In your case of 2x2 matrices, the problem would become apparent almost immediately!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using the [closed range operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73) in your for loop `0...self.rows`. This will include the upper bound of the range in the iteration, which in your case is out of bounds and will therefore crash.

You want to use the half-open range operator `..<` instead:

```
for row in 0..<self.rows {
    for column in 0..<self.columns {
        self[row, column] = matrixB[row, column] + self[row, column]
    }
}
```

This will iterate up to but not including the upper bound.

---

I would also note [@MartinR's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745743/swift-matrix-sum#comment62962353_37745743) – defining equality for the matrices to be solely based on the dimensions being the same seems illogical. Remember that equality implies *substitutability* (i.e if `a == b`, `a` and `b` are interchangeable).

I would consider changing your `==` to check both dimensions *and* values, and then implement your own dimension check in your `sumWith` method (or create a new method to compare dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your error is **Index out of range**

Replace your extension with this code.

```
extension Matrix: Operation {

    mutating func sumWith(matrixB: Matrix) throws -> Matrix {

        guard self == matrixB else { throw RisedError.DimensionNotEquals }

        for row in 0...self.rows - 1 {
            for column in 0...self.columns - 1 {
                self[row, column] = matrixB[row, column] + self[row, column]
            }
         }
        return self
    }
}
```

Hope it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
swift 4 - Addition 0f 3 x 3 Matrices

enum RisedError: Error {
        case DimensionNotEquals
        case Obvious(String)
    }
    func ==(lhs: Matrix, rhs: Matrix) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.rows) == (rhs.rows) && (lhs.columns) == (rhs.columns)
    }
    protocol Operation {
        mutating func sumWith(matrixB: Matrix) throws -> Matrix

    }
    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    //Matrix creation
        func matrixCreation(){
            var matrixA = Matrix(rows: 3, columns: 3)
            var matrixB = Matrix(rows: 3, columns: 3)
            matrixA[0,0] = 1.0
            matrixA[0, 1] = 2.0
            matrixA[0, 2] = 2.0
            matrixA[1, 0] = 3.0
            matrixA[1, 1] = 4.0
            matrixA[1, 2] = 4.0
            matrixA[2, 0] = 1.0
            matrixA[2, 1] = 1.0
            matrixA[2, 2] = 1.0
            matrixB[0,0] = 5.0
            matrixB[0, 1] = 6.0
            matrixB[0, 2] = 6.0
            matrixB[1, 0] = 7.0
            matrixB[1, 1] = 8.0
            matrixB[1, 2] = 8.0
            matrixB[2, 0] = 1.0
            matrixB[2, 1] = 1.0
            matrixB[2, 2] = 1.0

            var outputMartix = Matrix(rows: 3, columns: 3)
            print(matrixB , matrixA)
            do {
                outputMartix = try! matrixA.sumWith(matrixB: matrixB)
                print(outputMartix)
            }catch RisedError.DimensionNotEquals{
                print("Dimensions are not equal")

            }
        }

    }

    //Matrix Configuration

    struct Matrix {
        let rows: Int, columns: Int
        var grid: [Double]
        init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
            self.rows = rows
            self.columns = columns
            grid = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: rows * columns)
        }
        func indexIsValidForRow(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
            return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
        }
        subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
            get {
                assert(indexIsValidForRow(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
                return grid[(row * columns) + column]
            }
            set {
                assert(indexIsValidForRow(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
                grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    extension Matrix: Operation {

        mutating func sumWith(matrixB: Matrix) throws -> Matrix {

            guard self == matrixB else { throw RisedError.DimensionNotEquals }

            for row in 0...self.rows - 1 {
                for column in 0...self.columns - 1 {
                    self[row, column] = matrixB[row, column] + self[row, column]
                }
            }
            return self
        }
    }
```