# "fatal error: Index out of range"

Tags: swift, loops, byte

We have 2 fields with message and key. Convert them to bytes and use `^` for each byte of message and key (it can be less then actual message length, that is why we use % there)

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageToEncrypt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var encryptionKey: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cryptResult: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var decryptResult: UITextField!
@IBAction func encryptFunc(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mte = messageToEncrypt.text;
    let kte = encryptionKey.text;
    var mte_byteArray = [UInt8]();
    var kte_byteArray = [UInt8]();

    for char in mte!.utf8{
        mte_byteArray += [char]
    }
    for char1 in kte!.utf8{
        kte_byteArray += [char1]
    }

    var counT: Int =  mte_byteArray.count;
    var cryptedSum = [UInt8](count: counT, repeatedValue: 0);
    for i in 0...mte_byteArray.count{
        cryptedSum[i] = mte_byteArray[i] ^ kte_byteArray[i%kte_byteArray.count];
    }
    print(cryptedSum);
}
```

and here I have that issue

```
for i in 0...mte_byteArray.count{
    cryptedSum[i] = mte_byteArray[i] ^ kte_byteArray[i%kte_byteArray.count];
}
```

> fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: You want `for i in 0..<mte_byteArray.count {...}` (or `for i in mte_byteArray.indices {...}`) – see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37745743/2976878)

Comment: Oh God, it worked
Thank you friend